# Why tailwind css is not working with Laravel Valet, but it does work with 127.0.0.1:8000/

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css

I started using **Laravel Valet** just recently. I have a fresh new **laravel project + breeze** nothing else. Everything works just fine, but when trying to add additional **tailwind** classes, no further changes are being made on the views. Looks like the classes are not being recognized. And this happens when using **Laravel Valet**. Everything works fine when using `php artisan serve` with **127.0.0.1:8000** instead of what **Valet** provides my case: ***new_project.test/***. Any reason why this could happen? I also want to mention `npm run dev` and `npm run watch` are being executed and working.